# Derive that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k \ 2^{n-(k+1)} = 2^n-n-1$.

Tags: summation

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k \ 2^{n-(k+1)} = 2^n-n-1$.

How does one show a sum like this?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah: It doesn’t matter, since the $k=0$ term is $0$.

Comment: Induction will do nicely, or you may use the formula for a geometric series.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes Mister Brian with a great respect.

Comment: @person This is a combination of a geometric series and a arithmetic series, can I really just use the formula for a geometric series. Furthermore I would like to be able to show it by deriving it without knowing the equality, I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generalization:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\binom{k}{m}2^{n-(k+1)}
&=\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\binom{k}{m}\left(2^{n-k}-2^{n-(k+1)}\right)\tag{1a}\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\binom{k}{m}2^{n-k}-\sum_{k=m+1}^n\binom{k-1}{m}2^{n-k}\tag{1b}\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\binom{k}{m}2^{n-k}-\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\binom{k-1}{m}2^{n-k}-\binom{n-1}{m}+2^n[m=0]\tag{1c}\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\binom{k-1}{m-1}2^{n-k}-\binom{n-1}{m}+2^n[m=0]\tag{1d}\\
&=2\sum_{k=m-1}^{n-2}\binom{k}{m-1}2^{(n-1)-(k+1)}-\binom{n-1}{m}+2^n[m=0]\tag{1e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: $2^{n-(k+1)}=2^{n-k}-2^{n-(k+1)}$
$\text{(1b)}$: substitute $k\mapsto k-1$ in the right-hand sum
$\text{(1c)}$: handle the edge terms from the right-hand sum
$\text{(1d)}$: $\binom{k-1}{m-1}=\binom{k}{m}-\binom{k-1}{m}$
$\text{(1e)}$: substitute $k\mapsto k+1$ and pull a factor of $2$ out front
$\phantom{\text{(1e):}}$ so that the sum matches with $(n,m)\mapsto(n-1,m-1)$

Applying $(1)$ twice gives
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{k}{1}2^{n-(k+1)}
&=2\color{#C00}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{k}{0}2^{(n-1)-(k+1)}}-(n-1)\tag{2a}\\
&=2\color{#C00}{\left(2^{n-1}-1\right)}-(n-1)\tag{2b}\\[8pt]
&=2^n-n-1\tag{2c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: apply $\text{(1e)}$
$\text{(2b)}$: apply $\text{(1e)}$ to the red part
$\text{(2c)}$: simplify

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways. Induction is one, and another uses a bit of calculus, but a direct calculation reducing it to sums of geometric series is also possible, starting like this:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k2^{n-(k+1)}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^k2^{n-(k+1)}\\
&\overset{(1)}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=i}^{n-1}2^{n-(k+1)}\\
&\overset{(2)}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=i+1}^n2^{n-k}\\
&\overset{(3)}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-(i+1)}2^\ell
\end{align*}$$

$(1)$ is just reversing the order of summation, analogous to reversing the order of integration; $(2)$ is shifting the index of the inner summation up by $1$; and $(3)$ is substituting $\ell=n-k$ in the inner summation.

The inner summation is now a finite geometric series, which you should be able to sum, and once you’ve done that, you’ll find that completing the calculation is mostly just summing another finite geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Observe that your sum can be written as

$$S=2^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k(\frac 12)^k$$

Consider
$$F(x)=1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1}=$$
$$\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$$
$$F'(x)=\frac{x^{n-1}((n-1)x-1)}{(1-x)^2}$$

$$xF'(x)=x+2x^2+3x^3+...+kx^k+...$$

So,
$$S=2^{n-2}F'(\frac 12)$$

Answer (score 1):

Take $2^{n-2}$ outside the sum.
Use $\sum_0^{n-1}kx^{k-1}=\frac{d}{dx}\sum_0^{n-1}x^k=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$. Then let $x=\frac{1}{2}$ to finish off.